# Change the format of JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have JSON file shown by fetch() request. 
This is an example of what I get when I request form the database:

```
 [
    {
        "id": 3086206,
        "title": "General specifications"
    },
    {
        "id": 3086207,
        "title": "Features and Facilities"
    },
    {
        "id": 3086208,
        "title": "contacts "
    },
    {
        "id": 3086209,
        "title": "Communication"
    }
]
```

As you can see there is an array with 4 objects I want to change it to 1 object that has 4 objects in, like this:

```
[{
    "item1": {
        "id": 3086206,
        "title": "General specifications"

    },
    "item2": {
        "id": 3086207,
        "title": "Features and Facilities"

    },
    "item3": {
        "id": 3086208,
        "title": "contacts "

    },
    "item4": {
        "id": 3086209,
        "title": "Communication"
    }
}]
```

How can I change the JSON file? This is how I display data from JSON file.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/json', {
            method: 'get',
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            let Maindata = JSON.parse(text)
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Content'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
{
    "id": 3086206,
    "title": "General specifications"
},
{
    "id": 3086207,
    "title": "Features and Facilities"
},
{
    "id": 3086208,
    "title": "contacts "
},
{
    "id": 3086209,
    "title": "Communication"
}
]

const resultArr = [{}];

arr.map((value,index) => { resultArr[0]['item'+(index+1)] = value})
console.log(resultArr)
```

Comment: This (modifying an external array or object) is not the use case for `Array.prototype.map`. `Array.prototype.map` returns an array and should be used primarily as a way to generate a new array from an original array. `Array.prototype.reduce` is the better choice here. Other valid choices (though I prefer `reduce` to both) are an imperative loop (e.g. `for`) or `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with `ES6` Approach

```js
const arr = [ { "id": 3086206, "title": "General specifications" }, { "id": 3086207, "title": "Features and Facilities" }, { "id": 3086208, "title": "contacts " }, { "id": 3086209, "title": "Communication" } ];

const res = arr.reduce(
  (acc, item, i) => {
    acc['item' + (i + 1)] = item;
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);

//for ES6 approach
//let res = arr.reduce((a,b,c)=>(a['item'+(c+1)]=b,a),{})

console.log([res]) //unnecessary to use wrap array over the object
console.log(res) //i think its enough to call res.item1
```

Comment: While I agree that `Array.prototype.reduce` is the best / correct answer to this question, I think some slight modifications to the working example (making it more idiomatic by not depending on the comma / sequence operator and giving the callback arguments meaningful names) makes the example easier for beginners to understand.

Comment: Welcome @tex. Keep improving

Answer (score -1):

```js
 let data = [
      {
          "id": 3086206,
          "title": "General specifications"
      },
      {
          "id": 3086207,
          "title": "Features and Facilities"
      },
      {
          "id": 3086208,
          "title": "contacts "
      },
      {
          "id": 3086209,
          "title": "Communication"
      }

    ];

  let temp={};
  let num = 2;
  data.forEach((element, index) => {
    if( num > index){
    temp[`item${index+1}`] = element;
    }
  });
  let output = [temp];
  console.log(output);
```

In variable **num** you can define the number if you want to add braces dynamically. or remove condition.